# AdonisJS 'bouncer' package not working as intended

Tags: adonis.js

As described [here](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/authorization), I have implemented the authorization:

**start/bouncer.ts:**

```js
import Bouncer from '@ioc:Adonis/Addons/Bouncer'
export const { actions } = Bouncer
export const { policies } = Bouncer.registerPolicies({
  UserPolicy: () => import('App/Policies/UserPolicy'),
})
```

**app/Policies/UserPolicy.ts:**

```js
import { BasePolicy } from '@ioc:Adonis/Addons/Bouncer'
import User from 'App/Models/User'
export default class UserPolicy extends BasePolicy {
  public async before(user?: User) {
    return user?.isSuperUser
  }
  public async list(user: User) {
    await user.load('policies')
    return user.policies.some((policy) => policy.identifier === 'user:list')
  }
  // ...
}
```

**resources/vires/layouts/main.edge**

```html
@can('UserPolicy.list')
  <p>Can see users list</p>
@endcan
```

And I cannot see the paragraph. In fact, I placed `console.log` inside the action, but it didn't get executed. I don't know if I'm missing anything. Can anyone shed some lights onto it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gotcha! [This](https://docs.adonisjs.com/guides/authorization#before-hook) says:

- The actual action callback is never executed when a before hook returns a true or a false value.
- Make sure to return undefined if you want the bouncer to execute the next hook or the action callback.

These 2 statements were missed out. :)